# Turn On/Off Bluetooth in WPF Application

Tags: wpf, bluetooth, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I am working on a WPF app using Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10. I have a specific requirement in which I shall be able to do the following stuffs with The Bluetooth . The application shall run on Tablets so its understood that there shall be no hardware button to play with Bluettooth. My requirement is

1. Turn Off bluetooth using a toggle switch if it is ON and Vice Versa.
2. Turn ON/OFF its visibility status

I have been looking for with for over a while but couldnt find anything. I tried this piece of code without any success.Can anyone look into it ?

```
if (!BluetoothRadio.IsSupported)
{
   tbOutput.Text = "No Bluetooth Adapter found!!!";
} else
{
  if (BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode == RadioMode.PowerOff)
      BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode = RadioMode.Discoverable;
}
```